# import numpy causes Python crash on Windows Server 2012R2 VM

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem with numpy (python version 3.7.1 and numpy version is 1.16.1) in one of my VM (Windows Server 2012R2). I write test code to test and the numpy crash when perform **init**.

When I use pdb to step into the **init** of numpy, it crashed at line 208 when call dot method of x:
[image]
And from the output, it shows an Illegal Instruction error:
[image]

Due to some unfunctional requirement, we have to use numpy 1.16.1. Does anyone can help on this problem? Thanks a lot.

Update:
My test code is very simple, and the CPU of my host machine is: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz
[image]

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code

Comment: I have tried, but cannot replicate this error.  You may want to reinstall the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault is an illegal instruction in the openblas library, which is a highly optimized lineair algebra library used by `numpy`.

Openblas can be built to detect CPU features at runtime, *or* it can be built for specific CPU features like AVX vector instructions.

I suspect that your copy of openblas was built to use instructions that are not available on your CPU. You probably need a different openblas package (built to detect CPU features at runtime) or even a different numpy package.